How to initialize angular reactive form with different key values
I am trying to build angular form with given key names and values of that keys that are always the same. I have managed to build one form but output format is not quite the one I need.
keysToChange = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']

export interface PatchForm {
  [x: string]: FormControl<string | null>
  date: FormControl<string | null>
}

patchForm = this.fb.group({
  keysToChange: this.fb.array<FormGroup<PatchForm>>([]),
})

  initializeForm() {
    this.keysToChange.forEach((key) => {
      const formGroup = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
        [key]: new FormControl(''),
        date: new FormControl(''),
      })
      this.patchForm.controls.keysToChange.push(formGroup)
    })
  }

I get this output:

{
    "keysToChange": [
        {
            "key1": "",
            "date": ""
        },
        {
            "key2": "",
            "date": ""
        },
        {
            "key3": "",
            "date": ""
        },
        {
            "key4": "",
            "date": ""
        }
    ]
}

but I need more something like this:
export interface PatchForm {
  id: FormControl<string | null>
  date: FormControl<string | null>
}

then output like this:

{
  "key1": {
    "id": "string",
    "date": "2024-04-03T11:23:05.499Z"
  },
  "key2": {
    "id": "string",
    "date": "2024-04-03T11:23:05.499Z"
  },
  "key3": {
    "id": "string",
    "date": "2024-04-03T11:23:05.499Z"
  },
  "key4": {
    "id": "string",
    "date": "2024-04-03T11:23:05.499Z"
  }
}


problem I have is mainly creating types and initializing form because my eslint is not allowing unsafe use of type 'any' and I don't quite understand how to initialize keys for each FormGroup.

We need to create a formGroup and then use addControl to add each individual control with the key name and formgroup. Please find below working example, let me know if any doubts!
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export interface PatchForm {
  [x: string]: FormControl<string | null>;
  date: FormControl<string | null>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="patchForm">
      <div formGroupName="keysToChange">
        <div *ngFor="let item of iterKeys; let i = index" [formGroupName]="item">
          <input type="text" formControlName="id" id="id" name="id"/>
          <input type="date" formControlName="date" id="date" name="date"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    {{patchForm.value | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  keysToChange = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4'];
  name = 'Angular';
  fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  iterKeys: Array<string> = [];

  patchForm = this.fb.group({
    keysToChange: this.fb.group({}),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeForm();
  }

  initializeForm() {
    this.keysToChange.forEach((key) => {
      const formGroup = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
        id: new FormControl(''),
        date: new FormControl(''),
      });
      this.patchForm.controls.keysToChange.addControl(key, formGroup);
    });
    this.iterKeys = Object.keys(this.patchForm.controls.keysToChange.controls);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

I do however get the error Cannot find control with path 'keysToChange' --> (I am at angular 14 btw)) any ideas?

@JackOrlen Could you replicate the issue on stackblitz and share it back here for debugging?

not really . I think the problem comes from the fact we are declaring [formGroupName]="keysToChange" but Angular is looking for formControlName with that value ...

@JackOrlen keysToChange is set to formGroupName which looks for a formGroup, you are taking about formControlName!

I have updated stackblitz can you please have a look.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r2if1z?file=src%2Fmain.ts

@JackOrlen You share back the same stackblitz I shared, plz modify it replicate the error and share back or create a new question!

I think it should be ok now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78278913/cannot-find-control-with-path-angular

export interface PatchForm2 {
  id: FormControl<string | null>
  date: FormControl<string | null>
}


  keysToChange = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']

  patchForm = new FormGroup({});

  constructor() {
    this.initializeForm();

    console.log(this.patchForm.value)
  }

  initializeForm() {
    this.keysToChange.forEach((key) => {
      const _formGroup: FormGroup<PatchForm2> = new FormGroup({
        id: new FormControl(''),
        date: new FormControl(''),
      });

      this.patchForm.addControl(key, _formGroup)
    })
  }


output
{
    "key1": {
        "id": "",
        "date": ""
    },
    "key2": {
        "id": "",
        "date": ""
    },
    "key3": {
        "id": "",
        "date": ""
    },
    "key4": {
        "id": "",
        "date": ""
    }
}

