Cannot find control with path: Angular
I have an error even if my form works as expected.
I have creates stackblitz and the error I have is
chunk-BINLTDE4.js?v=f1352cb0:6833  ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'keysToChange -> Label 3 -> 2'
    at _throwError (@angular_forms.js?v=7ed29dd3:2642:9)
    at setUpControl (@angular_forms.js?v=7ed29dd3:2496:7)
    at _FormGroupDirective.addControl (@angular_forms.js?v=7ed29dd3:4087:5)
    at _FormControlName._setUpControl (@angular_forms.js?v=7ed29dd3:4611:39)
    at _FormControlName.ngOnChanges (@angular_forms.js?v=7ed29dd3:4560:12)
    at _FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (chunk-BINLTDE4.js?v=f1352cb0:5544:10)
    at callHookInternal (chunk-BINLTDE4.js?v=f1352cb0:6110:10)
    at callHook (chunk-BINLTDE4.js?v=f1352cb0:6128:5)
    at callHooks (chunk-BINLTDE4.js?v=f1352cb0:6099:9)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (chunk-BINLTDE4.js?v=f1352cb0:6068:5)

Link to stackblitz --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cxcfjt?file=src%2Fmain.ts
Thanks for your help.
Minimal Reproducible code
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export interface PatchForm {
  [x: string]: FormControl<string | null>;
  date: FormControl<string | null>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
   <form [formGroup]="patchForm">
      <ng-container formGroupName="keysToChange">
      <div *ngFor="let detail of detailsToDisplay; let i = index" [formGroupName]="keysToChangeKeys[i]">
          <ng-container [formControlName]="i">
                  <input matInput formControlName="id">
                  <input matInput placeholder="Choose a date" formControlName="date">
          </ng-container>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
</form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  keysToChange = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4'];
  name = 'Angular';
  fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  iterKeys: Array<string> = [];
  keysToChangeKeys = ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3']

  detailsToDisplay = [
    { label: 'Label 1', value: 'some value' },
    { label: 'Label 2', value: 'some value' },
    { label: 'Label 3', value: 'some value' }, ]

  patchForm = this.fb.group({
    keysToChange: this.fb.group({}),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeForm();
  }

  initializeForm() {
    this.keysToChange.forEach((key) => {
      const formGroup = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
        id: new FormControl(''),
        date: new FormControl(''),
      });
      this.patchForm.controls.keysToChange.addControl(key, formGroup);
    });
    this.iterKeys = Object.keys(this.patchForm.controls.keysToChange.controls);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);


what is keysToChangeKeys we need to use keysToChange since that is the key we are setting for the newly created controls!

Hello, preparing a StackBlitz is fine but you should also copy the corresponding code here. See How do I ask a good question : "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to [...] but also copy the code into the question itself"

@JackOrlen keysToChangeKeys has three elements, and keysToChange has four elements, they need to be equal length

I have updated code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ea8vpx?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Hello I still get the same error. I will now update code again.

Here is updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mubiuu?file=src%2Fmain.ts

keysToChangeKeys has three elements, and keysToChange has four elements, they need to be equal length in my opinion
But Here is an attempt to make the functionality to work, all we need to do is set the insert control keys names to the values in keysToChangeKeys array instead of keysToChange
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export interface PatchForm {
  [x: string]: FormControl<string | null>;
  date: FormControl<string | null>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
   <form [formGroup]="patchForm">
        <ng-container formGroupName="keysToChange">
        <div *ngFor="let detail of detailsToDisplay; let i = index" [formGroupName]="keysToChangeKeys[i]">
            <ng-container [formControlName]="i">
                    <input matInput formControlName="id">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Choose a date" formControlName="date">
            </ng-container>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
  </form>
  {{patchForm.value | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  keysToChange = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4'];
  name = 'Angular';
  fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  iterKeys: Array<string> = [];
  keysToChangeKeys = ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3'];

  detailsToDisplay = [
    { label: 'Label 1', value: 'some value' },
    { label: 'Label 2', value: 'some value' },
    { label: 'Label 3', value: 'some value' },
  ];

  patchForm = this.fb.group({
    keysToChange: this.fb.group({}),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeForm();
  }

  initializeForm() {
    this.keysToChange.forEach((key, i) => {
      const formGroup = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
        id: new FormControl(''),
        date: new FormControl(''),
      });
      const mappedKey = this.keysToChangeKeys[i];
      if (mappedKey) {
        this.patchForm.controls.keysToChange.addControl(mappedKey, formGroup);
      }
    });
    this.iterKeys = Object.keys(this.patchForm.controls.keysToChange.controls);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

You are looping in detailsToDisplay and accessing formGroupName from keysToChangeKeys[i] (i.e => 'Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3' ) and it is not present in your formGroup "keysToChange" because you are adding control in form group throug looping "keysToChange"
this.keysToChange.forEach((key) => {
   const formGroup = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
            id: new FormControl(''),
            date: new FormControl(''),
         });
   this.patchForm.controls.keysToChange.addControl(key, formGroup);
});

So Fix is make dynamic loop:
<form [formGroup]="patchForm">
   <ng-container formGroupName="keysToChange">
      <div *ngFor="let detail of patchForm.get('keysToChange')['controls']; 
            let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
         <ng-container>
            <input matInput formControlName="id">
            <input matInput placeholder="Choose a date" 
             formControlName="date">
         </ng-container>
      </div>
   </ng-container>
</form>

